# How to get all elements on a page except div's

Tags: javascript, web, dom, google-chrome-extension, browser

So I'm trying to apply some css to every element on a page, but I don't want the css to apply to div's. I am currently using `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` to select every element, but as far as I know there isn't anyway to filter out a certain element type. I think I found some code that does what I want but It was using jQuery and I don't want to use that in this project. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below selector that will select **all child element of `body` which is not `div`**

```
body *:not(div)
```

or

```
body :not(div)
```

```js
const allExceptDiv = document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(div)");

allExceptDiv.forEach(el => el.classList.add("highlight"))
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>

<div>This is div</div>

<p> This is para </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the not selector

```css
 body :not(div) {
     color: red;
 }
```

```html
<html><body>
<div>Hello</div>
<a>World</a>
</body></html>
```

Remember to include the `body`, otherwise, `body` will also be considered as an element that should have a `color: red` style.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not